# maven property ${project.artifact.selectedVersion.majorVersion}

Tags: java, maven

I see in many pom.xml files the use of this property:
${project.artifact.selectedVersion.majorVersion}

such as in:

```
<project>
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <groupId>my_group</groupId>
  <artifactId>my_artifact</artifactId>
  <packaging>pom</packaging>
  <version>1.2.3-SNAPSHOT</version>

  <properties>
     <ver>${project.artifact.selectedVersion.majorVersion}</ver>
...
```

This property is not in the standard maven: http://docs.codehaus.org/display/MAVENUSER/MavenPropertiesGuide

So, where is this variable defined?

I see that it has the build-helper-maven-plugin plugin: http://mojo.codehaus.org/build-helper-maven-plugin/parse-version-mojo.html

which can parse the variable into `majorVersion` and `minorVersion`,
but the default `defaultPrefix` is `parsedVersion.{majorVersion, minorVersion}`, 
instead of `project.artifact.selectedVersion.{majorVersion, minorVersion}`...
(and the `defaultPrefix` is not defined in those pom.xml files that I am looking at)

so, where is the variable `${project.artifact.selectedVersion.majorVersion}` defined?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The thing to do is usually to start from [the `MavenProject` JavaDocs](http://maven.apache.org/ref/3.0.5/maven-core/apidocs/org/apache/maven/project/MavenProject.html) and click through the property path.

[`MavenProject`](http://maven.apache.org/ref/3.0.5/maven-core/apidocs/org/apache/maven/project/MavenProject.html) -> [`.getArtifact()`](http://maven.apache.org/ref/3.0.5/maven-core/apidocs/org/apache/maven/project/MavenProject.html#getArtifact%28%29) -> [`Artifact`](http://maven.apache.org/ref/3.0.5/maven-artifact/apidocs/org/apache/maven/artifact/Artifact.html) -> [`.getSelectedVersion()`](http://maven.apache.org/ref/3.0.5/maven-artifact/apidocs/org/apache/maven/artifact/Artifact.html#getSelectedVersion%28%29) -> [`ArtifactVersion`](http://maven.apache.org/ref/3.0.5/maven-artifact/apidocs/org/apache/maven/artifact/versioning/ArtifactVersion.html) -> [`.getMajorVersion()`](http://maven.apache.org/ref/3.0.5/maven-artifact/apidocs/org/apache/maven/artifact/versioning/ArtifactVersion.html#getMajorVersion%28%29)

For every XML Element in a pom.xml, there is a corresponding JavaBean Property in `MavenProject`, and periods delimit paths to properties of properties.

Comment: Maven documentation for the win, again.